# SolrException: undefined field text

Tags: solr

I have installed solr 4.9.1.
This my schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="ayan_schema" version="1.5">
    <types>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField"
            precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
        <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
        <fieldtype name="syn" class="solr.TextField">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"
                    ignoreCase="true" expand="false" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldtype>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="email" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="skype" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="irc" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="twitter" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="syn_val" type="syn" indexed="true" stored="true" />
        <field name="all" type="string" docValues="true" indexed="true"
            stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    </fields>
    <defaultSearchField>name</defaultSearchField>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <copyField source="id" dest="all" />
    <copyField source="email" dest="all" />
    <copyField source="skype" dest="all" />
    <copyField source="irc" dest="all" />
    <copyField source="twitter" dest="all" />
</schema>
```

When I search using the name field I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1267)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getWrappedAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:433)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper.initReader(AnalyzerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:178)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:207)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:375)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:299)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:185)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:96)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:148)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:197)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1962)
    at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$5.call(SolrCore.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am not able to figure out the mistake I am doing.When I search using any field other than name I am able to search properly.
The query is :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=name%3Adennis+l*&fl=*%2Cscore&wt=json&indent=true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says "undefined field text". Which means that the search is being performed on a field named text. Can you paste the query parameters here to see what request parameters are and what is causing this issue.

Comment: Looks like you are using the default core named collection1 bundled with solr. The bundled solrconfig.xml has a default setting for "df" parameter that specifies the field to search on. Either change this to the name of your field ("all") or set the df parameter in the search query http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=name%3Adennis+l*&fl=*%2Cscore&wt=json&indent=true
&df=name)

Comment: is the df param used to override default search field?

Comment: yes df parameter is used to configure default search field

Answer (score 1):

Edit your query and add another parameter **debugQuery=true**

In this way you will see, in a dedicated section of the response, how Solr i terprets your query and where is the misunderstanding between what you want to do and what Solr effectively does